# Sudo-ing Apache for a particular vhost

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to manage several SVN repositories for a particular vhost in my system. I want those to be owned by a particular user in the system and **not** by `wwwrun/www`. The other websites hosted by Apache should be regularly executed by the unprivileged `wwwrun/www` user.

I'm using `worker`. How can I tell Apache that every request for a specific vhost must be served impersonating a specific user like I would do in IIS?

(This will also come useful when running FUDforum)

Comment: I found https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/suexec.html suExec. Does it work only for CGI/SSI or also with DAV_SVN and php-fpm over fcgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are custom branches of Apache that have a specific directive for running as a given user.

1. mpm-peruser
2. mpm-itk

Per-user is very mature and stable for use in production. As this occurs at Apache itself, it means all your modules will run as whoever you desire.

Comment: I've seen itk is a fork of prefork, and peruser looks like the same. I'm skeptic only because I chose worker because it has better performance with mod-mono. I'm considering your answer but I prefer keeping the worker for performance reasons... if I can!

Comment: I can't comment on mod_mono, I'm not familiar with it. But in terms of performance I haven't seen any overheads for PHP based apps. We built a custom branch of per_user that outperforms prefork, like for like. The multiplexers and queues work surprisingly well.

Comment: I've read on http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono (seek for "prefork") that "It is advisable to use the worker MPM with mod_mono. Unfortunately, PHP seems to not necessarily work with the worker MPM, so you may not be able to go this route.". It doesn't mean mono **doesn't work**, I believe it runs better. Since mod_mono still runs with prefork, I can still move to the peruser module once I've made sure that performs well with both PHP and mono. Also, if I move to peruser, I can throw php-fpm away :)

Comment: To be clear: **BOTH** Mono and PHP **run** with any worker. I was worried about performance (speed and memory consumption)

Comment: I wouldn't give any great concern, the difference is probably negligible anyway. Test with either and see how it actually applies to your situation.

Comment: mpm-itk is distributed in openSuse repository. I chose this. It *seems* to work fine ;)